# Are all backends affected by performance penalty when ingress-nginx has ssl passtrough enabled? Should I use seperate ingresses?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

As [ingress-nginx docs](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/) state enabling ssl passthrough (`--enable-ssl-passthrough`) "bypasses NGINX completely and introduces a non-negligible performance penalty."

Does this mean that *all* backends are affected by this performance penalty, or *only* those whose ingress has the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough`?

In my case, I'd like to proxy a Kafka cluster behind an nginx ingress, and Kafka demands ssl passthrough to be enabled. So would it be advisable to install two ingresses, one without ssl passthrough/performance penalty for the usual http traffic to the web application, and a second one with ssl passthrough solely for Kafka?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this mean that *all* backends are affected by this performance penalty, or *only* those whose ingress has the annoation "nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough"?

To answer this question, I will quote [the entire warning](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough):

> This feature is implemented by intercepting **all traffic** on the configured HTTPS port (default: 443) and handing it over to a local TCP proxy. This bypasses NGINX completely and introduces a non-negligible performance penalty.

It follows that all traffic that is directed to your HTTPS port (all pods with HTTPS traffic) will have a slight performance penalty as this bypasses NGINX itself. It shouldn't affect your HTTP traffic. So you shouldn't need to run a second ingress, but you can always do so to separate rules in two separate ingresses.